# Javascript AJAX call, 'GET' multiple values in URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str,true);
```

Is it possible to do this?

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str+"j="+str2,true);
```

I want a value to be stored in both q and j.

Comment: You're missing an `&`: `xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str+"&j="+str2,true);`

Comment: @Sirko Ahh i see thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

of course it is

just add an & before each additional parameter like this:

`xmlhttp.open("GET","BAConsultRecordsAJAX.php?q="+str+"&j="+str2,true);`

Comment: Omg thanks, it worked! I'm pretty new to javascript's Syntax haha

Comment: @Marcus - glad I helped but you need to do some reading on the subject. it has nothing to do with javascript syntax at all. It's actually a standard http get request with parameters.

Comment: okay noted i will go read up more on it! haha because i used to do only windows based application programming. I've only recently started learning website programming.